# Using javascript to get server information

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to rewrite a snipped of PHP into JavaScript, ideally passing as few as possible variables between the two. Are there any super-global variables in JavaScript that give similar information to the PHP `$_SERVER` array?

In JavaScript, `location` seems to give me a bit of useful information but what about something like the PHP equivalent of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?  I also have jQuery as a resource.

Comment: Can you perhaps be more specific as to exactly what properties you are interested in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`window.location` can be read or set and comes with properties such as `.pathname`, `.search`, `.protocol`, et cetera -- each of which will provide that particular aspect of the URL as a read-only value.

`document.referrer` will provide the referring URL as a string.  If you want the domain/path/query/et cetera to be separated from one another, you will need to do that yourself, or use a library which will provide it.

`document.cookie` will provide you a semicolon-delimited list of user/server-set cookies.
Again, turning that into an array or an object is on your own shoulders.
Your cookie string also has no access to expiration-times, nor applicable paths the particular cookie is set for -- security.

For most of the rest of the data, you're going to have to talk to the server -- the browser likes to keep client-side script in the dark about things (like the user's IP, or session-variables, or anything else which can be turned into a security-risk).

Comment: I think the window and document variables should be able to give me everything I need!

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the referrer -

```
document.referrer
```

But I think you are looking at this in the wrong way - JavaScript and jQuery are run client side - if you want server variables accessible - you'll have to pass them to the script - possible by means of an AJAX call.  You say that you have jQuery available - so you can use the [`.ajax()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to retrieve all the server data you'll need.