# How to get system resource information?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a Discord bot using the Discord.JS library, and I would like to make a command that lists the server's os, ram, and CPU usage. How would I do this?

Comment: Please explain your question more. Do you want that information from the user's own computer or the server on which the bot is running?

Comment: @T.Dirks I would like the server information, IIRC you cannot get the user's OS information from Discord.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659923/using-javascript-to-get-server-information

Comment: @T.Dirks Thanks, could you put that as an answer so I can mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, this might provide a solution:

[Using javascript to get server information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659923/using-javascript-to-get-server-information)